# Update data from table to mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

Is there any framework or technique to simply update data edited in table and stored in mongoDB

I am using angularjs, node.js and mongoDB.

My 'by hand' idea is to:

1. track edits in angular table that will return json with updated fields
2. send REST request for update edited fields with proper document id

Comment: [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), [Express](http://expressjs.com/)

Comment: ok, Mongoose is for server side. But still I need to send REST with data and translate into query

Comment: Why don't you use Angular `$http` ?

Comment: Yes to azium's point, you are using Angular, which has the tools you need for communicating with a server: `$http`

Answer (score 1):

Using the Angular JS, we can do all CRUD operation. For your question i have answer,

In HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in getList">

                      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                    <td>{{list.firstname}}</td>
                    <td>{{list.lastname}}</td>
                    <td class=" last"><button type="button" class="fa fa-edit btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit($index,list)"></button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
```

In controller,

```
 $scope.edit=function(idx,list){
    $scope.<name of ng-model>=angular.copy(list)
    flag=idx;        
}
```

and now in controller where to saving, check the data in save() function, where the list is existing in the table. If yes the call update(), else call add().